# How to change a dbeaver time zone to Brazilian time?

Tags: dbeaver

I need alter the standard value, to use properly the now() button option
When I click on set to current time the added date is 3 hours ahead.

Answer (score 3):

add the follow line to your dbeaver.ini (locate at C:\Program Files\DBeaver)

```
-Duser.timezone=UTC-3
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be set in Preferences > User Interface
[image]